# Can't show labels in angular nvd3 sunburst chart

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

How can I set to always show the labels in my sunburst chart? I have this plunker like in the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/emCcNv?p=preview

```
$scope.options = {
  chart: {
  type: "sunburstChart",
  height: 450,
  duration: 250,
  width: 600,
  mode: "size",
  groupColorByParent: true,
  labelThreshold: 0.04,
  showLabels: true,
  key: function (d,i){return d.name;},
  labelFormat: function (d){if(mode === 'count'){return d.name + '#' + d.value}else{return d+ ' '}},
}
```

doesn't do the job for me, but here http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/sunburstChart it somehow works if you check the "showLables" checkbox

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, solved by updating your nvd3 lib to 1.8.5.